# Add styling only to elements with a child

Tags: javascript, html

I have multiple `<p>` with the same class names, and only one has a child. I'm trying to only highlight the `<p>` that has a child, but my code highlights all of them.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var highlight = document.getElementsByClassName('parent');

  for (let i = 0; i < highlight.length; i++) {
    if (document.querySelectorAll(".parent .child").length > 0) {
      highlight[i].style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<p class="parent">
  Testing 1
</p>
<p class="parent">
  Testing 2
  <span class="child">
    test
  </span>
</p>
<p class="parent">
  Test 3
</p>
<p class="parent">
  Testing 4
</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

In recent browsers, you can do this with a single selector string - select `.parent`s which have a child with `:has(> .child)`.

```js
for (const p of document.querySelectorAll('.parent:has(> .child)')) {
  p.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
}
```

```html
<p class="parent">
  Testing 1
</p>
<p class="parent">
  Testing 2
  <span class="child">
    test
  </span>
</p>
<p class="parent">
  Test 3
</p>
<p class="parent">
  Testing 4
</p>
```

Otherwise, going with your curent code, you'll have to reference the element being iterated over (the `highlight[i]`), and call `querySelector` on it to see if that one element has any matching children.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var highlight = document.getElementsByClassName('parent');

  for (let i = 0; i < highlight.length; i++) {
    if (highlight[i].querySelector(".parent .child")) {
      highlight[i].style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<p class="parent">
  Testing 1
</p>
<p class="parent">
  Testing 2
  <span class="child">
    test
  </span>
</p>
<p class="parent">
  Test 3
</p>
<p class="parent">
  Testing 4
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use javascript for this
just use the has selector

```
p:has(span) {
    background-color:#f00!important
}
```